# How to updated an SWT TableViewer when the Table changes?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have an SWT [TableViewer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/index.html) which, of course, displays the contents of a [Table](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/index.html).  When I change things in the table the viewer doesn't automatically refresh to show the changes.  Specifically, I change the sort direction on one of the columns of the table, but the viewer will not update unless I call `viewer.refresh()`. It's easy enough to refresh the viewer in my listeners attached to the table, but this requires that the table's listeners know about the viewer.  The table is tightly coupled to it's viewer.

Whats the best way to have the viewer refresh without the table being tightly coupled with the viewer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what listeners you're hooking up on `Table` that you couldn't alternately hook up on `TableViewer` to get that as your source.  For example, instead of hooking up a `SelectionListener` on your `Table`, you can hook up an `ISelectionChangedListener` on the `TableViewer`.  In that case, now you'll get the `TableViewer` as the event source instead of the table.

Of course, it's possible that there are events that the `TableViewer` doesn't proxy appropriately.  In which case, I'd stick a reference to the `TableViewer` in the `Table`'s data when you create it.  For example:

```
Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.NONE);
TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(table);

table.setData("tableViewer", tableViewer);

table.addListener(SWT.DISPOSE, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event e)
    {
        Table table = (Table)e.widget;
        TableViewer tableViewer = (TableViewer)table.getData("tableViewer");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  (1) I didn't realize you could use a key when setting widget data.  (2) Part of the trouble is that TableViewer's selections changed event doesn't respond to the user selecting table columns. I simplified my initial problem, I actually have a Nebula Grid (which has the same interface as Table) which allows cells to span rows, which leads to problems when selecting a row with a spanned cell. I have a (perhaps hackish) label provider which attaches a paint event listener to the Grid, to perform the selection behavior I want. (But, I digress by going into such detail.) Thanks again.

Comment: Interesting - I've not played with Nebula Grid but it looks terribly useful.  I strictly use `Table`s, so I never really pay much attention to them and always just sling `TableViewer`s around (and if I do need the `Table`, just get it through the viewer) so I hadn't considered this.  The Nebula stuff looks cool, I should take some time to play with it some day.

Comment: Your first comment about using a key when setting widget data made me curious: I don't see a `@since` on `getData(String)` in the javadoc, but if my memory serves me, it's new-ish?  Maybe since SWT 3.1 or something?  Sorry, I'm too lazy to look, but something to be aware of if you're supporting ancient versions of Eclipse / SWT.